# PHP symlink into subdirectory

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a symlink with PHP specifying the original path and the link path.

My paths are:

```
/tx/file.jpg
/sym.php
```

And this is the code:

```
symlink("tx/file.jpg","tx/link.jpg");
```

And it doesn't work, it doesn't give me errors neither in the logs, it just doesn't create the  symlink.
I've even tried using:

```
symlink(getcwd() . "/tx/file.jpg", getcwd() . "/tx/link.jpg");
```

Without luck.

If instead I move the script in the /tx/ directory and I run:

```
symlink("file.jpg","link.jpg");
```

It works.
Why? How can I fix it? I'm on a CentOS 5 server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path of a symlink is relative to the directory the symlink resides in, **not** your current working directory! As such, the link you're creating is referring to what you'd call `tx/tx/file.jpg`, which doesn't exist. You will need to create it as:

```
symlink("file.jpg", "tx/link.jpg");
```